The dangers of overflow using sprintf and how to avoid them
I've been using an IDE making calls to the compiler without me having to configure much, but from the options I can see it seems my project is set to use gnu99 for the C Language Standard and gnu++11 for the C++ Language Standard, while using gcc version 4.2.1.
The project is running on embedded devices for IoT and it got to the point I needed to simulate some parts of it and my lazy go to is onlinegdb. There I noticed that I am probably building strings unsafely and I'm worried the project may be compromised and in need of an urgent update. I am pretty sure I designed the string sizes to never be overflowed with the data I'm passing to them, but that's only if I implemented it correctly and that's what I'm afraid I didn't do.
Here's a runnable example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    // example 1 works as expected initially - I think it is unsafe
    char testString1[6];
    sprintf(testString1, "123");
    sprintf(testString1, "%s456", testString1);
    printf("%s\n", testString1); // 123456
    
    // example 2 doesn't work as I expected - I think it is intrinsically safe though
    char testString2[6];
    snprintf(testString2, 6, "123");
    snprintf(testString2, 6, "%s456", testString2);
    printf("%s\n", testString2); // 456
    
    // example 3 what I found works and I think is safe (EDIT: I understand now it isn't after reading comments)
    char testString3[6];
    snprintf(testString3, 6, "123");
    snprintf(testString3 + strlen(testString3), 6, "456");
    printf("%s\n", testString3); // 123456

    // example 4 modified example3 for safety
    char testString4[6];
    snprintf(testString4, 6, "123");
    snprintf(testString4 + strlen(testString4), sizeof(testString4) - strlen(testString4), "4567");
    printf("%s\n", testString4); // 12345

    return 0;
}

And here's the output:
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:29: warning: ‘456’ directive writing 3 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 6 [-Wformat-overflow=]
    9 |     sprintf(testString1, "%s456", testString1);
      |                             ^~~
main.c:9:5: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 4 and 9 bytes into a destination of size 6
    9 |     sprintf(testString1, "%s456", testString1);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:15:33: warning: ‘456’ directive output may be truncated writing 3 bytes into a region of size between 1 and 6 [-Wformat-truncation=]
   15 |     snprintf(testString2, 6, "%s456", testString2);
      |                                 ^~~
main.c:15:5: note: ‘snprintf’ output between 4 and 9 bytes into a destination of size 6
   15 |     snprintf(testString2, 6, "%s456", testString2);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
123456
456
123456
12345

Example 1 is how I have been building my strings up to this moment. Unfortunately my IDE/compiler didn't warn me of this, but onlinegdb did, probably since it uses a different compiler or language standard.
Example 2 is my first try to make this safer after noticing the warnings on onlinegdb. I replaced sprintf with snprintf, gave it a size limit and kept filling it with the same pattern as on example 1. This did not work, filling it just with the new data. In fact, if I remove the additional "456" characters on example 2, testString2 ends up being printed blank.
Example 3 is how I found it to work great and I think it is safe.
I would like to ask:

Is example 1 safe? I think it isn't due to warnings on example 1 and 2.
Why doesn't example 2 work as I expected?
Is example 3 really safe? Can I start building strings like this safely?

EDIT1: Added example 4. From what I understood, snprintf second argument is the max number of characters to write to the string, not the max number of characters on that string, so to make it safer I subtracted the length of the string (I suppose it's the index where the null character is placed) from total size allocated to the string and now it is limiting the number of characters being written even if I try to write more than what fits.

Remember the 0-byte which terminates a string in C, it needs one byte from the declared length.

The behavior of snprintf(testString2, 6, "%s456", testString2); is not defined by the C standard because C 2018 7.21.6.5 2 says “… If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.” You should not use the same array in the output and the input of sprintf or snprintf.

You can enable additional warnings in your ide. Add -Wall -Wextra to your compile command line.

Example3 is not safe. It will write the null terminator out of bounds.

I think the first step should be to install a compiler that isn’t almost two decades out of date. And then crank up the warnings and compile in strict mode. Your code is very wrong.

@SimonGoater just added example 4, would this one be safe?

Aside: make use of the length returned by snprintf() instead of immediately calling strlen().

Your first two examples are wrong for the same reason: the output string overlaps with one of the input.  Doing so triggers undefined behavior.
This is mentioned explicitly in section 7.21.6.6p2 of the C standard regarding the sprintf function:

The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
is written into an array (specified by the arguments) rather than to
a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters
written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying
takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

The same language is also in section 7.21.6.5p2 regarding the snprintf function.
Your third example doesn't suffer from this problem, however the destination isn't large enough to store the desired string.  It needs room for the 6 characters you want to put in, plus a terminating null bytes.
Example 4 works because the second call to snprintf limits what is appended to the remaining length of the array.
You actually don't need sprintf or snprintf to do what you want.  You can simply use strcpy and strcat:
char testString[7];
strcpy(testString, "123");
strcat(testString, "456");

You could also use strncat which like snprintf allows you to specify a size limit (which, as in the snprintf case, should be the avalible space, not the total space).  There is also the strncpy function, however it is not advisable to use this function as it doesn't automatically null terminate the destination string in all cases.

Just added example 4, it's example 3 modified to limit the number of characters added to the string. Is this valid?
Can I use strncat and specify limits in any way too so that I ensure it doesn't write outside the string?

I'd advice explicitly against the usage of strncpy because every beginner thinks that it is the safer version of strcpy, just like strncat is the safer version of strcat.

@rmarques: using strncat() is more likely to cause bugs than to solve problems.  Avoid it.  Avoid strncpy() too, though it is easier to use correctly than strncat().  Note: strncat(dst, sizeof(dst), “long string”) tramples out of bounds if dst is shorter than the string, even if dst is an empty string.

@JonathanLeffler at least strncat() is guaranteed to place a nul terminator, but with strncpy() there is no such guarantee. Amazingly.

@WeatherVane — But strncpy() doesn't trample out of bounds when the size is specified as sizeof(target), unlike strncpy().  Neither is satisfactory or truly safe.  Both are hazardous.  But I refuse to use strncat() whereas I occasionally use strncpy(), usually with a subsequent assignment of a null byte in the last byte of the target string.

@JonathanLeffler I do too: after the call always write a terminator into the last byte regardless. But I prefer to be sure of the source and destination lengths/sizes in the first place. It's all very well truncating strings to prevent overflow, but what about the bit that was left? Wasn't it necessary?

@WeatherVane — It depends on context.  For things like file names, truncation is a security risk.  For text stored in a fixed size field in a database, truncation may be acceptable (albeit something that raises a warning, which will, of course, usually be ignored).  And yes, it is far better to know the sizes of everything in advance so that neither strncpy() nor strncat() is needed — memmove() or memcpy() is better choice.
